# event.charCode always returning 0

Tags: javascript, html

I have a page where I need to capture input from a user after they click on a part of the page (a div). Here's my code:

```
<html>
<body>
<div style="background-color: lightpink" onkeydown="onkeydown1(event)" tabindex="-1">
click me, then press a key
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function onkeydown1(event)
{
    alert(event.charCode);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/WRwBF/

It took me the longest time to get this far because FireFox doesn't by default allow a div to "have focus." Eventually I found out that setting the tabindex for the div allows it to be in focus and the onkeydown event works.

My problem now is that when I click in the div and press a key, the value "0" is returned regardless of what key is pressed. Why would this be happening, and how can I fix it?

I would very much appreciate any guidance you might be able to give!

Comment: The short version is: [browsers are dumb](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/keys.html). That QuirksMode article should explain everything. Basically, to get the `charCode` portably, you need to detect the `keyPress` event, and try `evt.charCode || evt.keyCode`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Read http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html.

Summary: using the `keypress` event is the only way to get reliable information about the character typed. The following will be good enough to get you the character typed in most situations:

```
var charCode = (typeof event.which == "undefined") ? event.keyCode : event.which;
alert("Character typed: " + String.fromCharCode(charCode));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `event.keyCode` or `event.which` (depending on browser) instead

Comment: `event.keyCode` might not do what you want if you want to be able to tell apart small letters and capital letters. (Or want to ignore modifier keys.)

Answer (score 0):

You got focus with the tabindex property, and you can tab to it, but there is no interface for a div to receive a key event.

You get those from text inputs and the window itself.

Comment: No. Once the element can receive focus, it can fire key events. http://jsfiddle.net/timdown/rLfF5/